# Как передать информацию с помощью NFC?

Tags: android, nfc, arduino

Добрый день.
Хочу поднять вот какую проблему. Хочу передать информацию из телефона (андроид) в ардуино посредством nfc-интерфейса, а именно используя специальный модуль rc522. Вот опорная статья http://robocraft.ru/blog/3004.html
Если с ардуино все более-менее ясно, то вот с андроид не понятно, как именно нужно передавать информацию (например, какие-нибудь символы), чтобы ардуино воспринимала телефон как карту?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/194344/
возможно поможет

Answer (score 1):

Один из режимов работы мобильного устройства с антенной для NFC - эмуляция NFC карты (Card emulation mode). [Здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html) общее описание. [Здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html) - более подробное.